# how to edit second value of vector pair

Tags: c++

```
typedef std::pair< string, string >  sw_key;
typedef std::vector< sw_key >  sw_keys;     
sw_key swkey;


sw_keys   vecSWKeys;
std::back_insert_iterator<sw_keys> it(vecSWKeys);
```

// Read sw_key and maintain it in vecSWKeys vector

```
pCPxml->FindAttrText( "/cpq_package/sw_keys/sw_keys_and/sw_key", "name", it);


for (deviceData=pXML->GetFirstChild(device); deviceData!=0; deviceData=pXML->GetFollowingSibling(deviceData) )
{        
    string sVal;
    pXML->FindFirstText( deviceData, &sVal );
    switch(count)
    {                               
     case 3:
```

//IN THIS LINE I WANT TO ASSIGN sVal to secand value of pair in vector but it  FAILS

```
     vecSWKeys[count].second=sVal;                      
     break;
    }
    count++;                
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Provide an SSCCE otherwise no one would be able to answer this.

Comment: @Rapptz We call it [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) these days. :-)

Comment: Sir It is compiling correctly , when i run the application it says "Debug assertion failed " Expression Vector subscription out of range .but when i comment this line  vecSWKeys[count].second=sVal; it works fine

Comment: @user3161006 Try `vecSWKeys[count].second = "Hello, world!";` and see if your program works. If it does, then the contents of `sVal` is corrupt. If it still crashes your program, then `count` is an invalid index of `vecSWKeys` (i.e., `vecSWKeys` does not have at least `count+1` elements).

Comment: the problem is not of this operation. I guess the vector is out of index in runtime

Comment: Contect of sVal is not corrupt . and I already tried  vecSwKeys[count].second = " Hello ";   this also gives same result

Comment: @Kaidul Islam Sazal , if this case what i need to do, any workaround?

Comment: @user3161006 well obviously `vecSWKeys.size() <= count`. The vector's too small to use `count` as an index.

Comment: Actually what you were afraid of is "how to assign value in second pair of string" is not the problem here obviously. The assignment here is syntactically correct. The problem is either `sval` is corrupted(but as you said it is okay, then okay) or the vector is out of bound index. Now it is your job to debug and check where the malfunction is occuring :)

Comment: @Herp Derpington  It is compiling perfectly sir . when execute "Debug assertion failed " Expression Vector subscription out of range"

Comment: @Kaidul Islam Sazal Sir I got the pointer infact I am extracting XML file may be in this loop there are more elements than existing vector lengt so when i try to assign value to the vector it might be failing now i will modify the code and check if this is the problem .

Comment: Thanku so much for all the time spent on going through the code and answering . Hope this works.